# How to Fix Apache Solr 8 Suggester 404 Error?

Tags: search, solr

I get an error 404 when I try to call the suggester. I configured it as
described in the Solr docs and restarted Solr 8:

My configurtion in solrconfig.xml:

```
<str name="name">mySuggester</str>

<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>

<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>

<str name="field">_text_</str>

<str name="weightField"></str>

<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>

<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
```

```
<str name="suggest">true</str>

<str name="suggest.count">10</str>
```

```
<str>suggest</str>
```

I use a nutch index, attached is a link to the schema.xml file:
https://paste.debian.net/1250732/

How to fix the 404 error?

Thank you